# Attempted to assign to read only property error when assigning to image src

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
profilePicDiv.innerHTML = "<img src='"+trainer.profile_pic_url+"'   class='img-responsive img-rounded img-raised'>"
```

I am trying to set the src of an image to a url returned from my firebase database, this method has worked on other pages on my website but not on this one, I have seen that using strict javascript means you cannot set propertys for certain elements but I have not used 'use strict' anywhere in my js file.

Could anyone tell me how to get past this problem and why this error comes up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the img element and then appending that as a child to the `profilePicDiv`:

```
var profilePicImg = document.createElement('img');
profilePicImg.src = trainer.profile_pic_url
profilePicImg.className = 'img-responsive img-rounded img-raised';
profilePicDiv.appendChild(profilePicImg);
```

Comment: Thank you I tried something else and it worked, but .className will save me time! Thanks